# Sencha - store.each() - Data are not available, they are only deep in data class

Tags: extjs

I have got:

```
Ext.define("catcher.view.Login", {
   extend: "Ext.form.Panel",
// creating login form, including selectfield
```

Store "Tournaments" is created in stores (autoload:true), have its model. Everyting is set.
need to dynamicly fill selectfield (still in view.Login class):

```
initialize: function(){
        var store = Ext.getStore("Tournaments");        
        var options = new Array();
        store.each(function(radek){
            options[radek.get("tournament_id")] = radek.get("tournament_name");
        });
    }
```

I do not want to use `store:"Tournaments"` config options, because of later form.submit(); does not send correct data from `selectfield`.

**There is the problem:** `console.log(store.getCount());` returns 0. Using `store.add({ ... })` I can add anything and getCount() returns corrent count (0 + add()).

Weird part: `console.log(store)` returns whole class including `data` object with all items inside. And next weird part - If I use the same code in controller, everything works, the Store is loaded properly and I can use mystore.each();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Store loading is asynchronous, by the time you're accessing it, it's not loaded. You need to listen to the store load event.

Something like:

```
store.on('load', function(storeRef, records, successful){
    //Loop through records
}, this);
```

[on() documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.JsonStore-method-on)

[load event documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.JsonStore-event-load)

Comment: Thanks, great. I thought that when the data are loaded in `data` class, they are also prepared for use.