# How can I check the value in the extjs store

Tags: javascript, extjs

The following is the code. I want to check the value that is loaded into the input1store, how can I do that?

I tried doing `alert(input1store)`, but it just returns the object, which doesn't help at all.

```
var input1store = new Ext.data.Store({
    fields: [{name: 'name'}],
    proxy:{
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'www.requesturl.com?format=json&source1',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'xml.result'
        }
    },
    autoLoad:false,
    sorters: [{property: 'name', direction: 'asc'}]
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sencha - store.each() - Data are not available, they are only deep in data class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15283033/sencha-store-each-data-are-not-available-they-are-only-deep-in-data-class)

Answer (score 0):

```
var records = input1store.getRange();

for(var i = 0, len = records.length; i < len; i++) {
    alert(records[i].get('name'));
}
```